# How to fix held broken packages?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

Trying to install libssl-dev on ubuntu 14.04.2

```
$ make
fatal error: openssl/sha.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I remove the held package and install the correct?

Comment: When's the last time you ran `sudo apt update` and/or `sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: Hi, I have done both between each steps.

Answer (score 34):

First, try entering this:
`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

This will go a long way toward fixing broken dependencies.
If that does not suffice, try:
`sudo apt-get install -f`

Then clean and update:
`sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update`

Then upgrade:
`sudo apt-get upgrade`
(say 'y' to upgrades)

If you get a message saying some packages are "held back", do this:

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Now do these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then see what happens when you enter:
`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

If it still doesn't work, try this:

```
sudo aptitude install libssl-dev zliblg-dev=1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1
```

If it still doesn't work, open up **Synaptic Package Manager** (It should be in your Launcher. If you can't find it, then at the Terminal enter `synaptic-pkexec`).

Search for `zlib1g-dev`.
If the box next to zlib1g-dev is not green, click on it and select "Mark for installation". If you see more than one version, pick `1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1` .
Then search for `libssl-dev`. If the box next to libssl-dev is not green, click on it and select "Mark for installation".

Then select "Apply".

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I did everything above and got the same error as in my original post. When I ran upgrade I got the following message. 
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic
  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

Comment: what gives `apt-cache policy zlib1g-dev` and `grep -P '^[ \t]*[^#[ \t]+' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`

Comment: @Bahamut Are you sure you mean "-P" ? For me, I get `E: Command line option 'P' [from -P] is not known.`

Comment: @SamHealey I modified my answer somewhat. Try what I suggest there, and let us know how it goes.

Comment: yes I mean -P ` -P, --perl-regexp
              Interpret the pattern as a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE)`

Comment: Never start a graphical program with sudo. gksudo some program or for synaptic use `synaptic-pkexec`

Comment: @Bahamut Why no sudo with graphical program?

Comment: @ gracious1 it breaks the rights in $HOME.

Comment: @gracious1 How do you know so many things? :)

Comment: I think `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update`  got me out of the woods already.

Answer (score 5):

You have to look for all files related with your package and purge them, then reinstall.

```
sudo dpkg --list
sudo apt-get purge "file-name"
```

repeat second command with every file and then just reinstall.

Comment: In the end this works, thanks for this Sir :)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo aptitude install lib_name_depending
```

worked for me when I wanted to install `libcurl4-openssl-dev` on my Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Several depending libs were not installed on my machine, and with use of aptitude tool, I manage to interactively install/downgrade necessary libs/package to be able to install `libcurl4-openssl-dev`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and fixed it as follows:
  1) Open Software & Updates utility
  2) Go to 'Updates' tab
  3) Make sure that all options are selected:

```
+ Important security updates
+ Recommended updates
+ Unsupported updates
```

4) `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

5) reboot

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed it was by when it said broken packages, there was a package listed on top of it. I ran sudo apt-get install (package name), and then I ran sudo apt-get upgrade, and then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

(Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS)
Using Synaptic Package Manager - Edit - Fix Broken Packages seemed to clear the logjam.