# Cannot install synaptics driver. apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics leads to broken packages

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies, touchpad, synaptic

I have just purchased a thinkpad and it has synaptic input device but ubuntu 18.4 does not come with synaptics touchpad driver. I am trying to implement the solution given [here](https://sangams.com.np/fix-ubuntu-18-4-touchpad-not-working-properly/) but running `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` leads to :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics : Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

apt policy xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-core outputs:

```
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.9.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.9.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-core:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3
  Version table:
     2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

I have tried [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389156/how-to-fix-held-broken-packages). But it does not solve my problem. Can somebody help me, i am really struggling with this wobbly touchpad

Comment: What does `apt policy xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-core` output?

Comment: Please note that Ubuntu-specific questions can be asked at Ask Ubuntu, per our [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Stephen Kitt - added the information in question