# Can not install git/ not able to install any kali linux tools

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, kali-linux, git

I just installed today. I mainly work with kali but i wanted to try this. Any help would be appreciated!

```
root@ubuntu:/home/<MY USERNAME># apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: This is a possible duplicate:  [How to fix held broken packages?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389156/how-to-fix-held-broken-packages). If you already tried something similar please provide your steps next time or edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

First try to fix the broken packages using apt itself

```
sudo apt install -f
```

This will resolve the dependency issues.

If it persists then try to reconfigure the packages using dpkg

```
sudo dpkg --configure-a
```

This dpkg configure command is for in case any installations were interrupted or incomplete. Should help with resolving common package problems. The apt will be good to go

Comment: what package would I have broken? I haven't downloaded anything yet.

Comment: @NhlaukoG (this is for my question above)

Comment: Fair point. But remember, Kali itself now installs packages manually during setup. Was also surprised, my internet or something weird crashed during my installation and I had broken packages on boot. I used those particular commands to get back on track.