# Dependency issues in the installation of Qemu

Tags: debian, qemu

I would like to install QEMU in my virtual machine Debian 10. But I get the following errors. How can I fix them?

```
root@debian:~# apt-get install qemu-system-arm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qemu-system-arm : Depends: libaio1 (>= 0.3.93) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libcapstone3 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libfdt1 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libspice-server1 (>= 0.13.1) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libvdeplug2 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libvirglrenderer0 (>= 0.7.0) but it is not installable
                   Recommends: qemu-system-gui (= 1:3.1+dfsg-8+deb10u5) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: qemu-utils but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: ipxe-qemu (>= 1.0.0+git-20131111.c3d1e78-1~) but it is not installable
                   Recommends: qemu-efi-aarch64 but it is not installable
                   Recommends: qemu-efi-arm but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389156/how-to-fix-held-broken-packages

Answer (score 0):

Running a full upgrade in some cases could fix this problem.

The problem could also be caused by a mis-configured `sources.list` file in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Please check your `source.list` to see if you have added repositories that are not supported.

You can do this by:

1. **Check sources.list by typing**

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   You can replace nano with an editor of your choice like gedit or leafpad.
2. **Check your repos in software center.**
   Navigate to your applications menu and search for `software & update`.
   A dialog will open. Click on the `other software` option and disable/remove any non-debian repo.
3. **Fix broken dependencies.**

   ```
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
4. **Update system packages.**

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
5. **Run a full upgrade to fix the problem**

   ```
   sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
   ```
6. **Install qemu-system-arm**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install qemu-system-arm
   ```

You can also refer to this.

1. [**How to fix held broken packages - Unix & Linux**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389156/how-to-fix-held-broken-packages)
2. [**Unable to correct problems you have held broken packages**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)